# Red screen when using require instead of import on React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I got red screen like below when using

```
var React = require('react-native');
var {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    View,
    TouchableHighlight,
    ActivityIndicatorIOS,
    NavigatorIOS,
    Image,
    Component
} = React;
```

[image]

However it works when using

```
import React from 'react';

import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    NavigatorIOS
} from 'react-native';
```

[image]

But if I changed it to

```
var React = require('react');
```

It came with another red screen:

[image]

The full code in my `index.ios.js` is like this:

```
'use strict';

//import React from 'react';
//
//import {
//    AppRegistry,
//    StyleSheet,
//    Text,
//    View,
//    NavigatorIOS
//} from 'react-native';

var React = require('react-native');

var styles = React.StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
        color: 'black',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        fontSize: 30,
        margin: 80
    },
    container: 
    {
        flex: 1
    }
});

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render() {
    //return React.createElement(Text, {style: styles.text}, "Hello World!");
      return <Text style={styles.text}>Hello World Again</Text>;
  }
}

class PropertyFinderApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <NavigatorIOS
                style = {styles.container}
                initialRoute={{
                    title: 'Property Finder',
                    component: HelloWorld,
            }}/>
        );
    }
}

//AppRegistry.registerComponent(
React.AppRegistry.registerComponent(
    'PropertyFinder', 
    function() { return PropertyFinderApp }
);
```

FYI: I was learning RN by following Raywenderlich's tutorial [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/126063/react-native-tutorial). So the full code is copied from there.

And here is the `package.json` for version info:

```
{
  "name": "PropertyFinder",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.28.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Component` was moved under *React* instead of *React-Native*:

```
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';

import ReactNative, {
  ...
} from 'react-native';
```

Of course you can do it as well with require, there's no restriction for that.

Comment: If I only write `var React=require('react-native');` no `component` was imported, still the red screen.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is not import or require but with what you are importing.

have you tried replacing

`var React = require('react-native')`

to

`var React = require('react')`

This changed kicked in after facebook decoupled react and react-native in one of their recent updates

Comment: Sorry I didn't show this situation before. Please check my update, it would still be another red screen. And it was because in that tutorial it was `require('react-native')`, so I just followed it.

Comment: the __fbBatchedBridge error usually goes away on npm restart or system restart